# Why do I keep getting a Null Exception Error?

Tags: java

I have three classes in my program. Ship.java, Cabin.java and Passenger.java. According to the program a single cabin can hold upto a maximum of 3 passengers. I'm trying to set passenger details but i keep getting this error

> Cannot invoke "classes.Passenger.setFirstName(String)" because
> "classes.Main.myShip[0].passenger[0]" is null     at
> classes.Main.main(Main.java:22)

**Ship.java**

```java
public class Ship 
    {
         public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         public static Cabin[] myShip = new Cabin[12];

         public static void main(String[] args)
         {

            for (int count = 0; count < 12; count++)
            {
                myShip[count] = new Cabin();
            }

            myShip[0].passenger[0].setFirstName("a");
         }
    }
```

**Cabin.java**

```java
public class Cabin 
    {

        int cabinNumber;

        Passenger[] passenger = new Passenger[3];
        
        public Cabin()
        {
         
        }

        public Cabin(int cabinNumber, Passenger[] passenger)
        {
            this.cabinNumber = cabinNumber;
            this.passenger = passenger;
        }

        public void setCabinNumber(int cNumber)
        {
            cabinNumber = cNumber;
        }

        public int getCabinNumber() 
        {
            return cabinNumber;
        }

 }
```

**Passenger.java**

```java
public class Passenger 
    {
         String firstName;
         String lastName;
         int expenses;

         public Passenger() 
         {

         }

         //Constructors
         public Passenger(String cabinFirstName, String cabinLastName, int pExpenses)
         {
              firstName = cabinFirstName;
              lastName = cabinLastName;
              expenses = pExpenses;
         }

         public void setFirstName(String cabinFirstName)
         {
              firstName = cabinFirstName;
         }

         public String getFirstName()
         {
              return firstName;
         }

         public void setLastName(String cabinLastName) 
         {
              lastName = cabinLastName;
         }

         public String getLastName() 
         {
              return lastName;
         }

         public void setExpenses(int pExpenses) 
         {
              expenses = pExpenses;
         }


         public int getExpenses() 
         {
              return expenses;
         }
 }
```

Please be kind enough to help me out.

Comment: the Constructor Cabin() does not exist in your code. That's why you get that error.

Comment: You need to define your Passenger[] passenger = new Passenger[3]; in the constructor  of cabin or somewhere before using a function within those classes.

Comment: You edited the question to add an extra constructor. And you changed the question entirely. That change invalidates prior answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is wrong. A ship can (and does) have cabins with no occupants.  You have provided no way to have unoccupied cabins.  Your cabins need to be fully booked before the ship can be built!

I would consider redefining your Cabin class to be constructed empty -- which means it would have a constructor with a signature like `Cabin()`, and then provide a way to assign Passengers to Cabins.  Maybe this would be a method in the Cabin class, like

```
boolean assignPassenger(Passenger p) {
   ... check occupancy...
   ... return false if full up ...
   ... otherwise add 'p' to the passenger array ...
   ... and return true ...
}
```

You're halfway there in that you're attempting to set the Cabins in the Ship by using a `Cabin()` constructor -- which is essentially an empty Cabin -- but you have not actually implemented a constructor with that signature.

What I'm getting at here is that, rather than just tweaking some Java, I think you should rethink it a bit. You'd want, I think, to be able to have unoccupied cabins and to be able to determine which cabins are occupied.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. The OP is clearly an inexperienced programmer. An answer that allows an inappropriate design is not in the interest of learning.

Comment: Maybe you should tell him to change the question instead of giving him an answer about something he is not asking and not understanding. Part of learning is to be able to ask the correct questions. At best this answer should be a comment.